# Changing object variables in an array of instance variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I process an array `@test_array` of integers, creating a new array `@cells` that contains an instance of class `Cell` for each element of the array, putting the value of the `@test_array` element into the instance variable `@value` of the newly created object?

Afterwards, I want to be able to change the `@value` of the different objects, and at the end of the program, I want to output an array of the all of the objects `@value`.

```
class Cells

  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

end

class Grid

  attr_accessor :test_array, :cells

  def initialize
    @test_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    @cells = []
    @test_array.each { |value| @cells << Cell.new(value) }
  end

  def put_values_of_objects_to_array
    @cells.value_to_a ????????
  end

end
```

This is what I get after running the code taking into account one of the answers:

```
2.0.0p247 :080 > cells = []
 => [] 
2.0.0p247 :081 > abc = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
2.0.0p247 :082 > abc.map {|value| cells << Cell.new(value)}
 => [[#<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313d8 @value=1>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313b0 @value=2>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331388 @value=3>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331360 @value=4>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331338 @value=5>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331310 @value=6>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312e8 @value=7>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312c0 @value=8>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331298 @value=9>], [#<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313d8 @value=1>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313b0 @value=2>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331388 @value=3>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331360 @value=4>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331338 @value=5>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331310 @value=6>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312e8 @value=7>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312c0 @value=8>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331298 @value=9>], [#<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313d8 @value=1>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313b0 @value=2>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331388 @value=3>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331360 @value=4>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331338 @value=5>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331310 @value=6>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312e8 @value=7>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312c0 @value=8>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331298 @value=9>], [#<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313d8 @value=1>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313b0 @value=2>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331388 @value=3>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331360 @value=4>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331338 @value=5>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331310 @value=6>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312e8 @value=7>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312c0 @value=8>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331298 @value=9>], [#<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313d8 @value=1>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313b0 @value=2>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331388 @value=3>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331360 @value=4>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331338 @value=5>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331310 @value=6>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312e8 @value=7>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312c0 @value=8>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331298 @value=9>], [#<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313d8 @value=1>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313b0 @value=2>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331388 @value=3>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331360 @value=4>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331338 @value=5>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331310 @value=6>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312e8 @value=7>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312c0 @value=8>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331298 @value=9>], [#<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313d8 @value=1>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313b0 @value=2>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331388 @value=3>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331360 @value=4>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331338 @value=5>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331310 @value=6>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312e8 @value=7>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312c0 @value=8>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331298 @value=9>], [#<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313d8 @value=1>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313b0 @value=2>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331388 @value=3>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331360 @value=4>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331338 @value=5>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331310 @value=6>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312e8 @value=7>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312c0 @value=8>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331298 @value=9>], [#<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313d8 @value=1>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313b0 @value=2>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331388 @value=3>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331360 @value=4>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331338 @value=5>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331310 @value=6>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312e8 @value=7>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312c0 @value=8>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331298 @value=9>]] 
2.0.0p247 :083 > cells
 => [#<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313d8 @value=1>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3313b0 @value=2>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331388 @value=3>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331360 @value=4>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331338 @value=5>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331310 @value=6>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312e8 @value=7>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc3312c0 @value=8>, #<Cell:0x007fe3dc331298 @value=9>] 
2.0.0p247 :084 >
```

Comment: In any case, `test_array.each {|value| @cells << Cell.new(value)}` should be `@test_array.each {|value| @cells << Cell.new(value)}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Cell
  attr_accessor :values

  @arrs = []    #Creates a "class instance variable"

  class <<self  #Creates an accessor for the "class instance variable"
    attr_reader :arrs
  end

  def initialize(values)
    @values = values
    self.class.arrs << @values    #Add the @values array to the "class instance variable"
  end
end

test_array = [1, 2, 3]

@cells = test_array.map do |num|   #Create the cells
  Cell.new(test_array.dup)
end

p @cells   

--output:--
[#<Cell:0x0000010085ffd8 @values=[1, 2, 3]>, #<Cell:0x0000010085ff88 @values=[1, 2, 3]>, #<Cell:0x0000010085ff60 @values=[1, 2, 3]>]


@cells.each_with_index do |cell, i|   #Change the last value of each cell's @values array
  cell.values[-1] = i
end


p Cell.arrs   #Show all the @values arrays of all the cells:

--output:--
[[1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3, 2]]
```

Now that you've added the Grid class to your post, you can add a class instance variable to the Grid class--rather than to the Cell class--to keep track of the arrays.

```
class Grid
  attr_accessor :cells

  TEST_ARRAY = [1, 2, 3, 4]

  @arrs = []
  class <<self
    attr_reader :arrs
  end

  def initialize 
    @cells = []

    TEST_ARRAY.each do |value| 
      new_cell = Cell.new(TEST_ARRAY.dup) 
      @cells << new_cell
      self.class.arrs << new_cell.values
    end

  end

end
```

> hey, thanks for this, however what I want is for one element of the
>   test_array to go into the object, and not the whole array.

That's not what this means:

> ...putting the value of the @test_array element into the instance variable @value

```
class Cell
  attr_accessor :values

  def initialize(value)
    @values = [value]
  end
end

class Grid
  attr_accessor :cells

  TEST_ARRAY = [1, 2, 3, 4]

  @cell_values = []
  class <<self
    attr_reader :cell_values
  end

  def initialize 
    @cells = []

    TEST_ARRAY.each_with_index do |value, i| 
      new_cell = Cell.new(TEST_ARRAY[i]) 
      @cells << new_cell
      self.class.cell_values << new_cell.values
    end

  end

end

mygrid = Grid.new
p Grid.cell_values

mygrid.cells.each do |cell|
  cell.values << 5
end

p Grid.cell_values


--output:--
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
[[1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: hey, thanks for this, however what I want is for one element of the test_array to go into the object, and not the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful exercise and you are very close. The stuff with declaring an array (`@cells = []`) and then looping over another array to do something with each element and adding the result to the new array  does work, but it is a pattern which is so common that many languages have an easier solution. In Ruby it's called ['map' aliased as 'collect'](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map). Demo:

```
class Cell

attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

end

class Grid

attr_accessor :test_array, :cells

  def initialize
    @test_array = [1,2,3,4]
    @cells = @test_array.map{|a_value| Cell.new(a_value)}
   end

  def put_values_of_objects_to_array
    @cells.map{|cell| cell.value}
  end

end


f = Grid.new
p f.put_values_of_objects_to_array #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, i have no idea why, when i run the command, it returns an array with 81 elements with 81 elements inside each one. So basically it gets 6561 Class objects. Any idea why? I checked the syntax over and over again and it's just like you posted...